# grep/awk 3rd column containing string

Tags: awk, grep

Example of string

```
blah:blah:example - 1234
blah1:blah2:example2 - 3213
```

What I want to check exists

```
- 1234
```

but numeric can be different

I know I can use

```
awk -F: '$3 ~ / - /'
```

to check if " - " exists, but how can I apply numeric possibilities?

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to check if after ' - ' there's some numbers? 
If you want to do this you can write 
`awk -F: '$3 ~ / - [0-9]+/'`

### More advanced solution

If you have an array of possible values for your last number (es. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) you could write something like this.

```
values=(1 2 3 4 5)
awk -v vals="$(echo ${values[@]})" \
'{if(match(vals,$3" ")){print $0}}' input_file.txt
```

This will print only those entries of `input_file.txt` having the last number in the `values` array you specified.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` command will display all lines from `file` that has a `-` in its penultimate whitespace-delimited column, and a positive integer in its last whitespace-delimited column:

```
awk '$(NF-1) == "-" && $NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/' file
```

The following `grep` command would do the same thing:

```
grep -E -e '-[[:space:]]+[0-9]+$' file
```

The `-E` is needed to understand the `+` modifier in the pattern, and `-e` is needed to stop `grep` from interpreting the `-` in the pattern as a command line option (`-e` could also be changed replaced by `--`, which signals the end of any command line options).